# When exporting a module like this, what happens?

Tags: node.js, factory

I was looking up some database connection Google searches when I saw something that exported an instance of a module as such

```
const foo = () => {
// Do stuff
};
...

module.exports = foo();
```

I don't know what this is called but how does nodejs treat exporting a function invocation vs an object or the function itself (without calling it)?

Thank you

Comment: There is no magic. The `foo` function will be called and its return value will be assigned to `module.exports`. In this case, since the `foo` function does not return anything, the value will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Molda really? I heard it's treated differently with the built in catching with nodejs but maybe I missheard this?

Comment: I added an answer, hopefuly it will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: "treat exporting a function invocation" — It doesn't export "a function invocation", it exports a value. The fact that value was acquired by calling a function is by the by.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo` function only gets called once no matter how many times you `require` the module.

This is very simplified explanation of what is happening behind the scenes in Node.js

```
// cache for modules
var modules = {};

// very simplified require function
function require(name) {

    // check cache
    if (modules[name])
        // so if it has already been required it returns the cached result
        return modules[name].module.exports;

    // it will resolve path to the required module
    // and loads the file content
    // not showing here

    var obj = { module: { exports: {}}};
    
    // node will wrap the code in a function similar to bellow
    function module(module, exports){
    
        const foo = () => {
        // Do stuff
        };
        ...
        
        module.exports = foo();
    
    };
    
    module(obj.module, obj.module.exports);
    
    // and now cache it
    modules[name] = obj;

   return obj.module.exports;
}
```